# OpenVPN + OpenWrt: server doesn't see devices in the client's network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, openwrt

I have an OpenVPN server. I'd like to get the access from there to the resources available on the client's network. The client network is managed by an OpenWrt-based router; it serves as an OpenVPN client.

Network for the server has 192.168.3.0/24 mask, local network on the OpenWrt router is 192.168.1.0/24, so there should be no conflicts.

The connection is successful, and I can ping my router from the server (`ping 192.168.1.1`) and backward (`ping 192.168.3.1` from the router).

But for some reason, all devices in the client's network are not available from the server.

**OpenVPN: Server configuration**

```
port 1194
proto udp4
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
client-config-dir ccd
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0"
```

**ccd/client**
    iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

**OpenVPN: Client configuration (/etc/config/openvpn)**

```
package openvpn

config openvpn 'client'

        option enabled 1
        option client '1'
        option dev 'tun'
        option proto 'udp4'
        list remote 'myvpnserver 1194'
        option resolv_retry 'infinite'
        option nobind '1'
        option persist_key '1'
        option persist_tun '1'
        option user 'nobody'
        option ca '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
        option cert '/etc/openvpn/client.crt'
        option key '/etc/openvpn/client.key'
        option remote_cert_tls 'server'
        option cipher 'AES-256-CBC'
        option verb '3'
        option status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
        option log /var/log/openvpn.log
```

I've added a corresponding interface and firewall rules on the router (based on the official manual):

**/etc/config/network**

```
config interface 'VPN'
        option proto 'none'
        option ifname 'tun0'
```

**/etc/config/firewall**

```
config zone
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option name 'vpn'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'
        option masq '1'
        option network 'VPN'

config forwarding
        option dest 'lan'
        option src 'vpn'

config forwarding
        option dest 'vpn'
        option src 'lan'
```

**Client log**

```
 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.8.0.6 pointopoint 10.8.0.5 mtu 1500
 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.5
 /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.8.0.5
 UID set to nobody
 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

**Server log**

```
MULTI: Learn: 192.168.1.219 -> client/83.220.239.243:21301 # 192.168.1.219 is one of the devices connected to the client network (to the router)
MULTI: Learn: 192.168.1.1 -> client/83.220.239.243:21301 # 192.168.1.1 is the router
```

These records appeared when I tried to ping 192.168.1.219 and 192.168.1.1 respectively.

I've enabled IP Forwarding on the server and on the client as [this article](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/265-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding) recommends.

I've also tried to disable the firewall on the router by using this command: `/etc/init.d/firewall stop`, but it didn't help either.

I did `tracert 192.168.1.219` on the server:

```
1    34 ms    39 ms    34 ms  10.8.0.6
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

10.8.0.6 is IP address of the router inside the VPN network.

What am I doing wrong?
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, pinging the IP of other interfaces on a router can be a false positive. Many routers have different rules when traffic is flowing to any of the router's interfaces (e.g. "Local" traffic).

It looks like the routing information on your VPN clients is incorrect, and/or you don't have a gateway for these clients. There are very odd things happening in your VPN client's routing table. For example, this route doesn't make any sense:

/sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.8.0.5

A /32 net mask is invalid. This is a route to no machines. The smallest valid mask is /30 (255.255.255.252). Also, your VPN clients seem to be picking up the wrong IP for your gateway; you said the router's IP was 10.8.0.6. Finally, your gateway's IP is in the DHCP pool of your OpenVPN server. After connecting a few clients 10.8.0.6 will be leased out to a VPN client, then you'll be in trouble.

It might be wise to spend some quality time with the openvpn reference document:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-0/